# html5 <canvas> framerate

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was thinking of making a game using javascript for the game logic and the HTML5 canvas element to animate the drawing. My goal is to write something that works in browsers and on newer smartphones. So I wrote up a quick program that moves 100 circles around on the screen and shows me the frame rate. I was fairly disappointed with the results:
Chrome: ~90 FPS
Firefox: ~ 25 FPS
iPhone: ~11 FPS

This was a pretty simple test so I don't like my chances when it comes to actually making a complete game. Is this the standard result from the canvas element or are there some tricks to make drawing faster, if you have any good links let me know? Is canvas just a toy at this point or can it be used for real world applications.

**Edit** Here's the code:

```
var ctx;
var width;
var height;
var delta;
var lastTime;
var frames;
var totalTime;
var updateTime;
var updateFrames;
var creats = new Array();

function init() {
    var canvas =document.getElementById('main');
    width = canvas.width;
    height = canvas.height; 
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    for(var i=0; i < 100; ++i) {
        addCreature();
    }
    lastTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    frames = 0;
    totalTime = 0;
    updateTime = 0;
    updateFrames =0;
    setInterval(update, 10);
}


function addCreature() {
    var c = new Creature(Math.random()*100,Math.random()*200);
    creats.push(c);
}

function update() {
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();
    delta = now-lastTime;
    lastTime = now;
    totalTime+=delta;
    frames++;
    updateTime+=delta;
    updateFrames++;
    if(updateTime > 1000) {
        document.getElementById('fps').innerHTML = "FPS AVG: " + (1000*frames/totalTime) + " CUR: " + (1000*updateFrames/updateTime);
        updateTime = 0;
        updateFrames =0;
    }

    for(var i=0; i < creats.length; ++i) {
        creats[i].move();
    }

    draw();
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    creats.forEach(drawCreat);
}

function drawCreat(c,i,a) {
    if (!onScreen(c)) {
        return;
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00A308";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

function onScreen(o) {
    return o.x >= 0 && o.y >= 0 && o.x <= width && o.y <=height;
}

function Creature(x1,y) {
    this.x = x1;
    this.y = y;

    this.dx = Math.random()*2;
    this.dy = Math.random()*2;

    this.move = function() {
        this.x+=this.dx;
        this.y+=this.dy;
        if(this.x < 0 || this.x > width) {
            this.dx*=-1;
        }
        if(this.y < 0 || this.y > height) {
            this.dy*=-1;
        }
    }

}

init();
```

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: I read that disconnecting the operations from the DOM would make things **Really** much faster, I think that they made a canvas element without connecting it anywhere in the DOM tree and blitted it over when drawing was done to one that is. But I'm not 100% sure - I just skimmed over the article quickly and decided that it wasn't what I was searching for at the moment.

Comment: I have the same exact problem as you (and the same purposes, building HTML Canvas based games to deploy them on iOS and Android Tablets and phones)

Check out my test (A Sky and Clouds, basically a bunch of circles moving)
http://www.gubatron.com/html5/sky.html

I get awesome FPS on the desktop, but the best I can get on a Galaxy Tab is 10-12FPS.

Been trying a lot of things, the only thing that helps is reducing the number of circles being painted.

This has me thinking that maybe I should work on a tiny portion of the canvas with much less resolution, then scale it out, will that fly?

Comment: I gave up on making canvas based games for phones and went back to making apps. Drawing at lower resolutions will increase your speed but you'll lose quality. I think anything that requies a complete redraw every frame is not going to work on a mobile device.

Answer (score 6):

In order to make animations more efficient, and to synchronize your framerate with the UI updates, Mozilla created a [mozRequestAnimationFrame() function](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/08/more-efficient-javascript-animations-with-mozrequestanimationframe/) that is designed to remove the inefficiencies of setTimeout() and setInterval(). This technique has since been adopted by Webkit for Chrome only.

In Feb 2011 [Paul Irish posted a shim](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) that created requestAnimFrame(), and shortly afterwards [Joe Lambert extended it](http://blog.joelambert.co.uk/2011/06/01/a-better-settimeoutsetinterval/) by restoring the "timeout" and "interval" delay to slow down animation ticks.

Anyway, I've used both and have seen very good results in Chrome and Firefox. The shim also fallsback to setTimeout() if support requestAnimationFrame() is unavailable. Both Paul and Joe's code is online [at github](http://gist.github.com/1002116/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I should clarify, after applying it to your code I'm getting 60fps in chrome and firefox. This 60fps is intentional as it synchronizes the frame update with the UI update. For a proper technical explanation why, see http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/05/03/better-javascript-animations-with-requestanimationframe/

Answer (score 5):

It's largely dependent on the JavaScript engine. V8 (Chrome) and Carakan (Opera) are probably the two fastest production-quality engines. TraceMonkey (Firefox) and SquirrelFish (Safari) are far behind, with KJS bringing up the rear. This will change as hardware acceleration enters the mainstream.

As for specific optimizations, we'd probably have to see some code. Remember that the canvas supports compositing, so you really only need to redraw areas that changed. Perhaps you should re-run your benchmark without the canvas so you know if the drawing operations really were the limiting factor.

If you want to see what can be done now, check out:
[js1k](http://js1k.com/)
[Bespin](http://bespin.mozillalabs.com/)
[Canvas-stein](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/creating-pseudo-3d-games-with-html-5-can-1/)

Comment: js1k is what lead me to think that canvas was ready for the mainstream. Having a closer look it seems that some get really good performance and others don't doing similar things. I profiled my code using console.prolfile(). ~90% of the time was spent drawing. I could possibly get some extra performance using composting but I would have to write a manager to work out what areas of the screen need to be redrawn. It would add a lot of complexity

Answer (score 3):

Arcs are math-intensive to draw. You can dramatically improve performance by using drawImage or even putImageData instead of drawing the path each frame.

The image can be a file loaded from a URL or it can be an image created by drawing on a separate canvas not visible to the user (not connected to the DOM). Either way, you'll save a ton of processor time.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a simple bouncing ball which gives you points if you click it.

It works fine in Firefox, Safari, Chrome and on the iPad. However, the iPhone 3G/3GS were horribly slow with it. Same goes for my older Android phone.

I am sorry but I do lack specific numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is the only browser thus far that I've seen high framerate results with.

You might also want to try the latest Preview of IE9. That should give you a decent benchmark of how the next generation of browsers (with hardware acceleration for HTML5) will handle your code.

So far, I've seen that IE9, Chrome 7, and Firefox 4 will all sport some form of hardware acceleration.

Comment: I know browsers are getting better but what about mobile? That was one of the main things I wanted to target. No point making something if I'm going to have to wait 3-5 years for a decent amount of people to be able to run it.

Comment: Well, what did you expect? You will have to add a GeForce card to your iPhone to speed this one up (and I must say, I'd love to see a picture of that). By the way: Chrome and the iPhone use the same rendering engine. What you see are only differences in calculating power.

Answer (score 0):

There's loads of optimizations to be done with Canvas drawing.

Do you have example code you could share?